# How to parse String Object with '\n' and \\\

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read `AWS SNS JSON`, but when I try to parse the string object in `jsonlog` I get a

```
SyntaxError:Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1
```

I tried to replace `'\n'` and `'\\'` but the string is not showing changes

```
var log = snslogs[i].jsonlog;
logs.push(JSON.parse(`${log}`));
```

I expect the `JSON.parse` to create an object.

Comment: paste your JSON string as well

Comment: I already did it

Comment: I think what @mehulmpt is saying is, please show the output of console.log (log) so we can see what your JSON string is before you parse it.  The contents of that log are not obvious from your post.

Comment: (node:22200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.arrangeSnsLogs (c:\Users\edwdelossantos\Desktop\Node Projects\hermes\helpers\sns.js:10:24)
    at awsSnsLogsSql.getSnsLog.then.response (c:\Users\edwdelossantos\Desktop\Node Projects\hermes\routes\snsLogs.js:13:24)

Comment: the comment above has the backslash and the error that im getting is sayng that the  breaking space is a charater

Comment: "{\n \"Type\" : \"Notification\",\n \"MessageId\" : \"9946ecd7-667a-5feb-9bbe-b975831461f0\"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My JSON.parse accepts the \n at the beginning of the string, not sure if that "position 1" in the error is misleading.

The problem I see is the trailing comma after the last field - that is not allowed in JSON.  So your inputs are not valid JSON, but if you really want to accommodate them anyway, try this:

```
JSON.parse(log.replace(',}$','}'))
```

or if the initial \n is a problem still, then this:

```
JSON.parse(log.replace(/\\n/,'').replace(',}$','}'))
```

You may need to play with the regex if you get other forms of the trailing comma (like with a space after it, etc).